# burning Ubuntu 12 image file on DVD in IMac

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded the iso image and on my IMac, I burnt it to a DVD, but my IMAC claimed that DVD is not readable, I put the same DVD on a windoes machine and it shows the contents of DVD fine. Then I put back the DVD on my IMAC and restart and once I see the black screen, where Ubuntu should load and start installation, nothing happens, the black screen stays forever. Any ideas how I can install ubuntu on my Imac using DVD?

Answer (score 0):

Hare's a complete guide on how to burn CD/DVD on [Mac OS X](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto#Mac_OS_X)

Comment: That is exactly what I have done!